# Get Full version 01.00.00.0000 instead of version 1.0.0.0 in arp window in wix

Tags: wix, wix3.11

When I installed a setup which is created with WIX, the version in ARP Window is displaying like 1.0.0.0 instead of 01.00.00.0000.

I was provided Version="01.00.00.0000" in Bundle.wxs file, but I have no idea why in ARP Window the version is displaying as 1.0.0.0

Is there any way to format the version to 01.00.00.0000 in Bundle.wxs file? And even when I checked in Setup.exe properties,the File version and Product version of a Setup is displayed as 1.0.0.0 instead of 01.00.00.0000

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
When I bind the version of an MSI, the the full version with format xx.xx.xx.xxxx is displaying.

```
  <Bundle Name="Sample Setup"
          Version="!(bind.packageVersion.MsiPackageId)"
```

Here MsiPackageId is the id of MsiPackage in chain element in Bundle.wxs like below

```
<Chain>
<MsiPackage Id="BATestSetup" />
</Chain>
```

But I'm don't know why when version="01.00.00.0000" is defined in Bundle.wxs, the version is displaying as 1.0.0.0 and when msi version is binded,the version is displaying as 01.00.00.0000.

Please suggest me if anyone knows.